# How to Upgrade React Native Version 0.66.3 to 0.70.6?

Tags: react-native

Currently, my project running on the **0.66.3** version I need to upgrade to react native version **0.70.6**. So I have used to following command

> npx react-native upgrade

After running this command showing some error I have attached a screenshot please refer.[image]

I am also trying the manual way using react native helper but some files are not available in my project.
so anyone please tell me how I will upgrade my project version?

After Run npx react-native run-android my build was created successfully but 3 errors showing in the metro bundler. I have attached a screenshot of the metro bundler error.
[image]

Comment: Have you try ```npm install react-native @0.70.6```?

Comment: Yes after run npm install react-native @0.70.6 build was created successfully but 3 error showing in metro bundler.

Comment: These errors are in code so not an any issue with setup of react native.

Answer (score 2):

you can also refer this official documentation for this

& it will also helps you if you got any error.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/upgrading

Answer (score 1):

you can specify a React Native version and pass it as an argument:

> npx react-native upgrade 0.70.6

Comment: Thanks for answer @Refka. I have pass version also but same issues facing.

Answer (score 0):

Since upgrading an application can break functionality in your app if you do not know what is needed to be changed.  the upgrade is tells you to visit the pages to go through and see what has changed throughout the upgrading process.

Other as that I am just needing more information regarding to what is not working. Since upgrading is more as just running a command, its about reading the documentation and see what part is missing and what they replaced the files with. The missing files could be straight-out deprecated and not working with the new version.

As always check the debugger and read every message throughout and visit all links given and see the documentation regarding the upgrade differences, find out if there are any log files you could look at, and talk with people in your company / group of react-native about this.

"Some files are not available in my project"
This part might just be able to google and see if this is still supported or not in the version it could be phased out, or not supported in the version. that's where versioning comes in to play.

I am unsure what files and which libraries are deprecated based on your Opening Post, this needs more information, to help us, help you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the advice. I have just run the command - npm outdated so its showing 12 packages outdated. So I have to upgrade that package and then upgrade react native version. after that, I am facing the same issues in pic no 2 above question.

Comment: Module "hermes" is not registered as callable, is what you need to fix.
Sometimes this seems to help:
` cd android `
` ./gradlew clean `

Other times it might be that you need to register hermes in your application somehow, so it becomes available to the application.

Comment: It also says some variable style has something it does not recognize, which might be removed due to upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

I found by changing react-native - index.js and react-native/Libraries/Text - index.js

Follow this link for output:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/3f629049ba9773793978cf9093c7a71af15e3e8d

Don't know whether it is the right way or not....